# Regex for string between 2 strings c#

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the message string out from this VMG file. I only want to strings after the Date line and before "END:VBODY"

The best I got so far is this regex string BEGIN:VBODY([^\n]*\n+)+END:VBODY

Anyone can help refine it?

```
N:
TEL:+65123345
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VENV
BEGIN:VBODY
Date:8/11/2013 11:59:00 PM
thi is a test message
Hello this is a test message on line 2
END:VBODY
END:VENV
END:VENV
END:VMSG
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use regex.  Much simpler to collect any line after BEGIN:VBODY is seen until the line is END:VBODY

Comment: Hey Spaceghost, do you have any idea of what a sample c# code for that would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex, you can modify your current regex a little, because the $0 group has what you are looking for.

```
BEGIN:VBODY\n?((?:[^\n]*\n+)+?)END:VBODY
```

Basically what happened was `([^\n]*\n+)+` turned into `(?:[^\n]*\n+)+?` (turning this part lazy might be safer)

And then wrap that whole part around parens: `((?[^\n]*\n+)+?)`

I added `\n?` before this to make the output a little cleaner.

---

A non-regex solution might be something like this:

```
string str = @"N:
    TEL:+65123345
    END:VCARD
    BEGIN:VENV
    BEGIN:VBODY
    Date:8/11/2013 11:59:00 PM
    thi is a test message
    Hello this is a test message on line 2
    END:VBODY
    END:VENV
    END:VENV
    END:VMSG";

int startId = str.IndexOf("BEGIN:VBODY")+11; // 11 is the length of "BEGIN:VBODY"
int endId = str.IndexOf("END:VBODY");
string result = str.Substring(startId, endId-startId);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
Date:8/11/2013 11:59:00 PM
thi is a test message
Hello this is a test message on line 2
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/O7BAr8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Regular Expressions,

```
        string text = @"N:
        TEL:+65123345
        END:VCARD
        BEGIN:VENV
        BEGIN:VBODY
        Date:8/11/2013 11:59:00 PM
        thi is a test message
        Hello this is a test message on line 2
        END:VBODY
        END:VENV
        END:VENV
        END:VMSG";


string pattern = @"BEGIN:VBODY(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9\r\n.\S\s ]*)END:VBODY";//Pattern to match text.
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);//Initialize a new Regex class with the above pattern.
Match match = rgx.Match(text);//Capture any matches.
if (match.Success)//If a match is found.
{
        string value2 = match.Groups["Value"].Value;//Capture match value.
        MessageBox.Show(value2);
}
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/6tgaFI).

and now a non-regex solution,

```
        string text = @"N:
        TEL:+65123345
        END:VCARD
        BEGIN:VENV
        BEGIN:VBODY
        Date:8/11/2013 11:59:00 PM
        thi is a test message
        Hello this is a test message on line 2
        END:VBODY
        END:VENV
        END:VENV
        END:VMSG";

        int startindex = text.IndexOf("BEGIN:VBODY") + ("BEGIN:VBODY").Length;//The just start index of Date...
        int length = text.IndexOf("END:VBODY") - startindex;//Length of text till END...
        if (startindex >= 0 && length >= 1)
        {
            string value = text.Substring(startindex, length);//This is the text you need.
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No match found.");
        }
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/FqgJfK).

Hope it helps.